# How to create nested loops in x86 assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Is it possible to create nested loops in x86 assembly language?

I'd like to translate this psedocode into correct x86 assembly code (using [MASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler) syntax), but I'm not sure how to initialize each loop counter here. Is it even possible to declare local variables in x86 assembly (as in most other programming languages)?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        for(var k = 0; k < 10; k++){
            mov eax, i + j + k;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question has a deceptively similar title to this one, but it's mostly irrelevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398672/nested-loop-in-x86-assembly?rq=1

Comment: Also, this question might be relevant (even though it got a large number of downvotes for no apparent reason): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890648/how-to-set-local-variable-assembly-x86

Comment: Given that your C code ultimately gets translated into machine code, the answer to both questions is a definitive yes, no need to ask.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Why was this question downvoted? Is there anything ambiguous about it, and is there anything I can do to improve it?

Comment: I didn't feel enough effort had been put into it.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I guess that's understandable - I've only been studying assembly language for the last 3 months, and that makes me look stupid, when compared to the rest of the assembly language community.

Comment: Don't denigrate yourself. Do more research.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. Since every computer program eventually boils down to assembly - it is naturally the most powerful language possible (excluding direct bit manipulation).

The actual code depends on your system, compiler and applied optimizations, but basically it should be something like this (example for 2 nested loops, not 3):

```
           mov ecx, 0

outerLoop:

           cmp ecx, 10
           je done
           mov ebx, 0

innerLoop:
           mov eax, ecx        ; do your thing here
           add eax, ebx

           cmp ebx, 10
           je innerLoopDone
           inc ebx
           jmp innerLoop

innerLoopDone:

           inc ecx
           jmp outerLoop
done:
```

Note, you don't need local variables, you've got general-purpose registers for the usage that you need. If you insist on having variables, you can use memory addresses for that and read/write using register pointers.

Comment: I would just push CX before inner loop and pop it after.

Comment: @MartinJames There are many, many ways to do this. Specifically push/pop will be slower, if that's a concern

Comment: These loops work, but they look like un-optimized compiler output (a direct transliteration of the C structure).  This is not idiomatic for asm, where you normally have the `jcc` at the bottom, and no `jmp` at all.  So you fall through to exit the loop.  It does nicely show using separate registers for separate loop counters, though.  (and re: Martin's point: push/pop CX and using a slow `loop` instruction is a 16-bit idiom that's no longer useful or relevant.)  Overall, worth an upvote, esp for the last paragraph.

Comment: Isn't nesting done via `enter` and `leave` while local variables are stored in the stack? Of course doing that way is rather unoptimized, but I believe that should be the general concept

Comment: @christopherwestburry: What you mean apply for function calls on a x86 machine. Nested loops don't need to touch the stackframe.