# Nested Loop in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, for-loop, nested-loops

I am newbie in assembly language and i couldn't handle the nested loop statement.
I want the same expression in such as the other languages like:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  for(j=0;j<10;j++){
     statements....
  }
}
```

I want this expression in assembly language.
Thanks...

Comment: Why not just compile it and study the resulting machine code?!

Comment: Which assembly language? What architecture are you targeting?

Comment: I am using x86 architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example I wrote using inline assembly in C, I've tested it in Visual Studio which uses Intel notation. I'm going to count in `eax`, which is the register used for function return values, all iterations of the loops (i.e. 100). `ebx` holds the `i` counter and `ecx` holds the `j` counter.

Be careful when you use these if you use them inline, `ecx` is used for the `this` reference inside objects and it's also used by `mul` and `div`. You can use whatever register you like or even the stack. I use `xor` to reset the counters since the `xor` operation is cheaper than a `mov eax,0` operation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int countLoops()
{
    _asm
    {
        xor eax,eax
        xor ebx,ebx
        xor ecx,ecx


outer_loop :
        cmp ebx,10
        je final
        add ebx,1

inner_loop:
        cmp ecx,10
        je reset_inner_loop
        add ecx,1

        add eax,1

        jmp inner_loop

reset_inner_loop:
        xor ecx,ecx
        jmp outer_loop

final:

    };
}

int main(void )
{
    int numOfLoops = countLoops();
    printf("%d\n", numOfLoops);
    return 0;
}
```

This question has also been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995696/how-to-create-nested-loops-in-x86-assembly-language).

Answer (score 4):

Let's break this down one step at a time. The first step is to break up the `for` into its separate pieces:

```
    i=0;
    do {
        j=0;
        do {
            /* statements.... */
            j++;
        } while(j < 10);
        i++;
    } while(i < 10);
```

The `while` is mostly just a test and a jump:

```
    i=0;
second:
    j=0;
first:
    /* statements.... */
    j++;
    if(j < 10)
        goto first;
    i++;
    if(i < 10)
        goto second;
```

Next, rename the variables so they have the names of registers:

```
    ebx=0;
second:
    ecx=0;
first:
    /* statements.... */
    ecx++;
    if(ecx < 10)
        goto first;
    ebx++;
    if(ebx < 10)
        goto second;
```

Now it's so close to assembly it's trivial to convert:

```
    mov ebx,0          ;ebx=0;
second:
    mov ecx,0          ;ecx=0;
first:
                       ;/* statements.... */
    inc ecx            ;ecx++;
    cmp ecx,10         ;if(ecx < 10)
    jb first           ;goto first;
    inc ebx            ;ebx++;
    cmp ebx,10         ;if(ebx < 10)
    jb second          ;goto second;
```